# count multiple strings in R, group by those strings

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like this:

```
Points      Assists      Steals
Player A    Player B     Player B
Player B    Player C     Player A
player C    Player C     Player A
```

And I'm trying to get a data.frame output like this:

```
           Points     Assists      Steals
Player A    1          0            2
Player B    1          1            1
Player C    1          2            0
```

As you can see, I want it to count the number of times that each player appears in each category. I'm able to do this for one column using `table()`, but can't figure out how to do it for multiple columns. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `gather` into long format, get the `count` and `spread` to wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df1) %>% 
     count(key, value) %>%
     spread(key, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     value Assists Points Steals
#*    <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 Player A       0      1      2
#2 Player B       1      1      1
#3 Player C       2      1      0
```

---

Or we use `melt` with `table`

```
library(reshape2)
table(melt(as.matrix(df1))[3:2])
#         Var2
#value      Points Assists Steals
#  Player A      1       0      2
#  Player B      1       1      1
#  Player C      1       2      0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Points = c("Player A", "Player B", "Player C"), 
Assists = c("Player B", "Player C", "Player C"), Steals = c("Player B", 
"Player A", "Player A")), .Names = c("Points", "Assists", 
"Steals"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: is there a data.table way to do this ? I am not sure how I would do.
I love the table melt way, simple and clever

Comment: @denis Thanks.  You can do `dcast(melt(setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE)[], id.var = 'rn'), value ~variable)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detail of akrun solution for data.table package. It is possible to have a single line, but I expanded it to several understandable steps.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df1)
DT[,id := 1:.N]
plouf <- melt(DT, id.var = c("id"))
dcast(plouf, value ~variable)
```

gives

```
      value Points Assists Steals
1: Player A      1       0      2
2: Player B      1       1      1
3: Player C      1       2      0
```